# c# System.InvalidOperationException: The type foo was not expected

Tags: web-services

This question is tied in with this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814627/silverlight-webservice-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-notfound) that I asked
I have this webservice that returns a class that within itself has a list of classes. When I try to call the method the following exception is being thrown:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The
>   type
>   YambushiDataClass.SCharacterProjectile
>   was not expected.

This is the class that it said it did not `expect` :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace YambushiDataClass
{

    public class SCharacterProjectile : SProjectile
    {
        public int? characterProjectileId { get; set; }
        public string projectileName { get; set; }
        public int? characterId { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 2 days bashing my brain in trying to solve the problem apparently I tried to fill the list public `List<SProjectile> projectileList = new List<SProjectile>();` with type SCharacterProjectile which inherits from SProjectile therefore could not be serialized