# WCF and What does this mean?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight-4.0

I have a WCF where all the calls work. All of them to silver light.  But this one call it says it cannot find, yet it exists and it also shows silver light side.  I am stumped for the lat 4 hours.  Any ideas?

This works:

```
_client.GetHandSetsCompleted += new EventHandler<GetHandSetsCompletedEventArgs>(_client_GetHandSetsCompleted);
_client.GetMarketsCompleted += new EventHandler<GetMarketsCompletedEventArgs>(_client_GetMarketsCompleted);
_client.GetCountByKeyCompleted += new EventHandler<GetCountByKeyCompletedEventArgs>(_client_GetCountByKeyCompleted);

_client.GetHandSetsAsync();
_client.GetMarketsAsync();
```

But as soon as I hit this:

```
private void UsrExchangeExportClicked(object sender, ExchangeQuerySetArg e)
    {
        XchangeQuerySet x = new XchangeQuerySet();

        x.End = e.End;
        x.Start = e.Start;
        x.Handset = e.Handset;

        //x.Markets = new ObservableCollection<int>(e.Markets);

        _client.GetCountByKeyAsync(x);

    }
```

It throws the error.  Makes  no sense.

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException was unhandled by user code
Message=The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
StackTrace:
   at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result)
   at ExWarranty.XchangeRef.XchangeServiceClient.XchangeServiceClientChannel.EndGetCountByKey(IAsyncResult result)
   at ExWarranty.XchangeRef.XchangeServiceClient.ExWarranty.XchangeRef.IXchangeService.EndGetCountByKey(IAsyncResult result)
   at ExWarranty.XchangeRef.XchangeServiceClient.OnEndGetCountByKey(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
InnerException: System.Net.WebException
   Message=The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   StackTrace:
        at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
        at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   InnerException: System.Net.WebException
        Message=The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
        StackTrace:
             at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
             at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass5.<EndGetResponse>b__4(Object sendState)
             at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__1(Object sendState)
        InnerException:
```

Comment: there are lot's of reason for "remote server returned an error: NotFound."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to browse or hit the "GetCountByKeyAsync" web method from Fiddler or IE.

Try to generate a request and hit the method from fiddler and see if you get back a success response. If that works then inspect the request from the application through fiddler to see what is causing the issue.

Make sure that the object being passed "XchangeQuerySet" is serializable.

Also to get some info on server side you can enable tracing. To enable tracing follow this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It means that there might be an error on WCF server side. Try checking activity tracing or eventlog for more info.

Also check a possible duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814627/silverlight-webservice-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-notfound)